# IsMobileDevice Google Bot problem

Tags: c#, bots

i have a website that have 2 verisions 1 righular and the other fo mobile
  it"s working great , but when google bot research my site ,
  my site shown on google as amobile ver.
  i think google bot pass the line:

```
if(Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
   ....redirect to the mobile ver (Not good for google it"s not the right ver)
```

you know a way to prevent that google refer to the mobile site

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is by default, the method Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice returns true for any User Agent it doesn't know about.

The trick is to add another .browsers file that identifies all the bots (this will happen with all of them, Yahoo, MSN, etc.) as NOT mobile devices.

I put a ticket in about this and explain it in detail here:
http://mdbf.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=3906

Comment: HI,
i use the solution you provide and i test it on 
facebook in the line add link facebook crawlers the site
and it refer it to mobile.

mybee you have a solution for this?
and thier it a way to test hoe google noe crawlers my site?
thanks